Minolta XG-1 - is the rewind crank supposed to stop when turning or does it have a free-turning-mechanism?
I am fairly new in the realm of film photography. I recently purchased a Minolta XG-1 and i couldnt be happier with it.
Now i have a question regarding the rewind crank. Is it normal that, when the film is loaded, you still can twist the rewind crank as if you are rewinding the film back into the roll? I didnt push the release button, that one is still in its normal position.
I know, this is very specific, but i would appreciate any information. Is there some kind of mechanism which allows the crank to be turned freely without influencinh the film?
Thank you all in advance, and have a beautiful weekend :)
David

Congratulations on dipping your toes into film photography!
A clue that the film has been properly loaded is to watch the rewind knob when you advance the film. It should spin as the film is pulled out of the cartridge.
In a properly loaded film camera it is possible to take up slack in the film can by turning the rewind knob, but you shouldn't be able to turn it more than 1 or 2 turns before you feel resistance and it stops.
The other possibility (and we've all done it at least once) is that when you loaded the camera you didn't properly engage the film leader in the takeup roller (or properly seat it so the camera could autoload the leader). In this case the camera may look like it's working properly- the shot counter may advance normally- but the film isn't moving. Also in this case you will be able to turn the rewind knob freely after some initial resistance. You will have pulled the leader back into the can and it'll happily flip for however long you want to turn the knob.

Thanks so much for your tips, i will see what i can do and how the photos will turn out :) i really appreciate it!!!

@david.graphy One easy way to find out is to get in a COMPLETELY DARK space with absolutely ZERO light. Open the back of the camera and feel along the edges of the film to see if there's any on the take-up spool or not. Try to stay on the edges, so you don't get a fingerprint on the image area.

As an additional point of advice: It's best to shoot a couple of manual dark frames with the lens cap on and advance the film to the zero position before checking the rewind crank.  The initial attachment to the takeup spool has to be weak in order to break it when rewinding the film so it takes a roll or two onto the spool to really secure things.
